# Filters in HBASE

Tags: php, filter, hadoop, hbase, stargate

How can i use the following Filters in HBASE efficiently by PHP?
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/branches/0.90/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/

Comment: Something I got using Stargate, Like fetching data using URL, using http:/localhost:8080/tablename/rowkey I can list all column family values.

Answer (score 0):

You can always port the code to PHP. But if you don't feel up for that. The only other option i know of is the Java Bridge.

I never used it before. But you should be able to do things like:

```
$filter = new Java("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.BinaryComparator", "bin value");
```

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/working_with_the_java_bridge.htm