# HBase Filter Language in PHP with Thrift

Tags: php, hbase, thrift

I'm looking for a way to use the HBase Filter Language in PHP.

The HBase Book's [chapter on Thrift](http://hbase.apache.org/book/thrift.html) seems formal and provides some filters for user to access HBase in PHP. A sample PHP code are also provided in this page, but I can not find any APIs in thrift (such as `$client->scannerOpenWithFilterString(...)`). I even checked the [thrift definition file for HBase 0.92.0](https://people.apache.org/~stack/hbase-0.92.0-candidate-1/hbase-0.92.0/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift), but it has no interface for `scannerOpenWithFilterString`.

Versions used: `Hadoop 0.20.203.0`, `Hbase 0.90.4` and `thrift 0.8.0`.

Does anyone know how to use PHP with filter features to access HBase?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Filters in HBASE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348721/filters-in-hbase).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-). To make sure you get quick, useful answers, be sure to follow the tips in [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Hbase filters for Thrift API were implemented in v.0.92
There's a function named scannerOpenWithScan(), which takes 2 parameters - table name and TScan object.

You need to generate php classes for thrift using Hbase.thrift file, provided in hbase 0.92+ release

```
thrift -gen php Hbase.thrift
```

In TScan object you can set startRow, stopRow, timestamp, columns, caching and filterString - which is exactly what you need.

Example: get rows 00100, 00200 and 00300

```
$flt = "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:00[1-3]00')";
$scan = new TScan(array("filterString" => $flt));
```

or

```
$scan = new TScan();
$scan->setFilterString($flt);
```

and finally

```
$scanner = $client->scannerOpenWithScan("table_name", $scan);
while ($result = $client->scannerGet($scanner)) {
  ...
}
```

For information about filterString syntax and available filters see attachments here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4176